# Button position changes because of texview size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, textview

I have a `TextView` which will show different text on click of button. But the problem is, button position changes because of the `TextView` size. I don't want the button position to change without using margin. Please help.

My XML code for design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.arnab.androiddevelopmentfundamentals.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/ui_and_events"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MyTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="@string/my_text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="@string/change_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/change_2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My java code for button click.

```
package com.example.arnab.androiddevelopmentfundamentals;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView MyText;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MyText);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == button1){
            MyText.setText("You have clicked button 1");
        }
    }
}
```

So, how to to fix this problem without using margin.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the button position changes after `onclick` event.

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of layout you want to create?

Comment: For the button you have `android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/MyText"` and `android:layout_below="@+id/MyText"` which puts the button relative to the TextView. So if you don't want it to change according to the `TextView` then you will have to drop these dependencies

Comment: do you want the buttons to be stay in the center or the right side?

Comment: at the orginal position - center @AnoopSS

Comment: Just use a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: check my answer @Arnab its the solution for both things which you want! one stop moving the buttons second they will stay in the centre place

Comment: then replace `android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/MyText"` with `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Comment: @AnoopSS thanks. your suggestion worked

Comment: @rizwanatta I will try your suggestion. thanks

Comment: It would be better if you use linear layout and set gravity to center horizontal and orientation to vertical, by this everything will come in center, as your text will increase it will push other components to bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't use `android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/MyText"` for button , button will move at the end of the text, if the text length changes try to use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.arnab.androiddevelopmentfundamentals.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/ui_and_events"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MyTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="@string/my_text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="@string/change_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/change_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**REMOVE**

```
 android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/MyText"
```

from your button One! its getting your button1 attached to the right/end of your text. and as button1 is attached to button two so both of them move while the text changes.. after removing the above stated property from button2 you will see both buttons will come on the left/start  of the position

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="zxczxc"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MyTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="asdas"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="abc" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="qwe" />
```

If you want your button to be centered always, then this is the solution using `layout_gravity` and `LinearLayout` as container tag(root tag)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/MyTitle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
       android:text="zxczxc"
       android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/MyText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/MyTitle"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
       android:text="asdas"
       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/MyText"
       android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="abc" />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:text="qwe" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution is to use `LinearLayout` for this purpose since your requirement is a vertically oriented linear list of items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  tools:context="com.example.arnab.androiddevelopmentfundamentals.MainActivity">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/MyTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="@string/ui_and_events"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/MyText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:text="You have clicked button 1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="@string/change_1"
     />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="@string/change_2"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This aligns the objects central-horizontally and line them perfectly one after the other

Comment: This is not an optimal solution. Suggestion to use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` just to keep the button below `TextView` isn't an ideal solution.